# Error preparing transaction in JBOss PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jboss, prepared-statement, spring-transactions

When am delete the object through JPARepository  am facing the exception like max transactions hint : Make max transactions as non zero value.To fix this problem I have set the max transaction as 100 in postgre.conf and it works good . But I am not convinced with this fix and I want to know the source of this problem .

Please see the log and help me out with your suggestions.

```
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.deleteJurisdiction(Unknown Source)
    at com.essvote.webresults.web.controller.jurisdiction.JurisdictionControllerImpl.deleteJurisdiction(JurisdictionControllerImpl.java:217) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:74) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.essvote.webresults.web.filter.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.doFilter(AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.java:82) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at com.essvote.webresults.web.filter.ClientInfoFilter.doFilterInternal(ClientInfoFilter.java:63) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at com.essvote.webresults.web.filter.ActiveJurisdictionFilter.doFilterInternal(ActiveJurisdictionFilter.java:175) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: maximum number of prepared transactions reached
  Hint: Increase max_prepared_transactions (currently 1).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:331)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.prepare(PGXAConnection.java:301)
    ... 122 more
```

Comment: Offtopic question: Why do you want to use a two-phase commit?

Comment: That's why I asked you. If you don't know what a 2-fase commit is, why do you want to use it? If seen horrible application & database performance because of some default behavior in Java of using 2-fase commit for everything. Using prepared statements are fine, but prepared transactions (!) should ring a bell. More info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

Comment: How I can you say that am using 2 false commit because I don't know where I have used ?

Comment: Because of the error message: "ERROR: maximum number of prepared transactions reached"

Comment: Yes initially it was zero and error log suggesting me to set non zero value . If I set 100 application works well. What will be the problem here whether its with code or any database configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62951/discussion-between-sridhar-and-frank-heikens).

Comment: Presumably JPARepository is using 2PC, probably via JTA, and presumably to sync multiple data sources. If you're only working with one datasource you probably don't need it. It might have a way to turn it off. The docs don't really say much about it unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks . How I can resolve this issue ?